# Eclipse 4.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 - "no such file" error

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I would like to install eclipse 4.4. I did everything step by step with this site:

http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/03/13/how-to-install-eclipse-4-3-kepler-standard-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-lts-3264bit-linux-easy-visual-guide/

Now it is what I got after step 6 when I try to start eclipse:

```
zaba@zaba:~$ ls /opt/eclipse/ 
    about_files    configuration  eclipse.ini   icon.xpm     
    plugins about.html     dropins        
    epl-v10.html  notice.html  readme artifacts.xml  
    eclipse        features      p2    
zaba@zaba:~$ ls /usr/local/bin/ 
    eclipse 
zaba@zaba:~$ eclipse 
    bash: /usr/local/bin/eclipse: no such file or directory
zaba@zaba:~$
```

As you can see teoretically everything is on its place: 'eclipse' file in /opt/eclipse and its link in /usr/local/bin - I made it as in tutorial, by:

```
ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since "A third-party application in /opt is supposed to be self-contained"

it should run through

/opt/eclipse/eclipse

if it does not, there is a problem either with your user or the executable, try just copying it to ~/bin

Comment: There was a problem with executable definately. After 3rd download it suddenly works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a mismatch on 64-bit and 32-bit in your operating system and eclipse version.